# Matrix conversion in a particular cluster Structure

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, matrix

I am trying to convert the Distance Matrix I got after calculating Euclidean Distance and taking Matrix form of it,  to a manual defined clustered pattern.
In my case, this is the matrix suppose which normal pattern 
[image: Normal Matrix with Cluster Order 1234]

Suppose, this is the desired cluster order, I have to convert i.e. from **1 2 3 4** to **3 1 2 4**, I want to have something like this. I do not want to do it manually since my matrix size is 40 X 40.
[image]

It is not clicking to my mind, I can code but algorithm is not coming to my mind. If you could help or someone has done something like this before. Please help me out with it.

I tried reading the data from csv with the help of d3.csv which gives the desired result of 1234 like this :

```
d3.csv("final.csv", function(loadeddata) {
mydata = loadeddata.map(function(d) {return [+d["1"], +d["2"] , +d["3"], +d["4"]] ;});
```

to

```
d3.csv("final.csv", function(loadeddata) {
mydata = loadeddata.map(function(d) {return [+d["3"], +d["1"] , +d["2"], +d["4"]] ;});
```

so that I can get the matrix in desired clustered format but it did not work coz it shifting whole column to the desired place but not shifting the element wise.

**Here is another try I made**

```
            var iMax = 4;
            var jMax = 4;
            var newdata = new Array();

            for (i=0;i<iMax;i++) {
               newdata[i]=new Array();
              for (j=0;j<jMax;j++) {
              newdata[i][j]=0;
             }
            }
var arraycomb = [3,1,2,4];

          for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
              for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                newdata[arraycomb[i]][arraycomb[j]] = mydata[i][j];

              }
              }
```